# Search an array stored in a Session

Tags: php, mysql

I pull a list of permissions from a the DB using and put them into an array;

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_permissions)) {
    $_SESSION['permissions'][] = $row;  
}
```

The contents of the session variable then looks like this;

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
        ["permission_name"] => string(15) "acl_assets_read"
    } 
    [1]=> array(1) { 
        ["permission_name"] => string(16) "acl_assets_write" 
    } 
}
```

below is the output using print_r instead which makes it easier to read.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [permission_name] => acl_assets_read ) [1] => Array (     [permission_name] => acl_assets_write ) )
```

I've read about using array_search and think it should work. I've tried to use the following to search for a permission;

```
if (array_search('acl_assets_read', $_SESSION['permissions'])) {
    echo "true";   
}
```

The problem i have is that even though the result is there, it keep returning false. The syntax looks correct to me.

Comment: `array_search` doesn't search recursive.

Comment: array_search matches the input to the elements of an array. You are searching for a string in an array that doesn't contain strings, it contains other arrays, which in turn contain strings. So that won't work.

Comment: Isn't it var_dump that is adding those bits though?

Comment: @Nathan can i see how you are adding the permissions to the array... with that i'll give you an answer... edit your question to show it

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you add the entire row (which is an array of its own) from your database into the `$_SESSION['permissions']`-array, forming a sub-array for each time it iterates the values from the database.

This means that all values in `$_SESSION['permissions']` are arrays, not strings. This in turn means that you cannot search for a string like that.

If you have stored the values you are interested in, in a column named `permissions` in the database, you simply need to add that element only to your `$_SESSION['permissions']`-array, like this

```
$_SESSION['permissions'][] = $row['permissions'];
```

This will add the string from that row into an element in the array `$_SESSION['permissions']`.

---

It's also worth noting that [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)  returns the *key* of the array, where as the first element will have an index (key) equal to 0. This means that the very first element of your array would really look like `if (0) { /* code */ }`. This will return to false (`if (0) == false`), so you should perhaps look into using [`ìn_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), which returns a boolean `true/false`.

```
if (in_array('acl_assets_read', $_SESSION['permissions'])) {
    echo "true";   
}
```

---

Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, and you shoud [stop using them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) if you can.

Comment: Unless you are using PHP 5.4.x or lower. But `This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0.`

Comment: It's a statement that you should stop *if you can* - simply because `mysql_` functions are out of date. Most people are on at least PHP 5.5, if you are on a lower version, that alone could be a reasonable argument to change host. But that's not the issue here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`array_search` will work for you but you need the proper `array` to search.

Take a look at this:

```
$arrOne = array("one", "two");
$arrTwo = array(array("one"), array("two"));

$key = array_search("one", $arrOne);

var_dump($key); // int(0) is the index of where the value was found

$key = array_search("two", $arrTwo);

var_dump($key); // bool(false) because "two" != array("one") or array("two")
```

Notice that the second `array_search` will return `false` because a `string` does not equal an `array`.

If you had:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(15) "acl_assets_read"
    [1]=> string(16) "acl_assets_write"
}
```

instead of:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
        ["permission_name"] => string(15) "acl_assets_read"
    } 
    [1]=> array(1) { 
        ["permission_name"] => string(16) "acl_assets_write" 
    } 
}
```

then your `array_search` would find the proper `string`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer :

```
$userdb = array(array("permission_name" => 'acl_assets_read'),array("permission_name" => 'acl_assets_write'));
$key = array_search("acl_assets_write", array_column($userdb, 'permission_name'));

if($key != ''){
  echo 'true';
}
```

If needle found $key show key of needle. If needle is not found $key show blank.